# What exactly is a "Nobita face"?

Tags: doraemon, joshiraku

After Gankyou in Joshiraku removes her glasses, her eyes change to '3' characters.

[image: Kukuru, Tetora, and Gankyou with '3' eyes; subtitle "So her glasses were actually suppressing her..."]

Marii then exclaims:

[image: Marii; subtitled "Why the Nobita face?!"]

I understand Nobita is a character in Doraemon, but I haven't found any information online either of pictures where Nobita has his glasses off, or any references to a "Nobita face".

Can someone explain this joke further?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Doraemon Wikia](http://doraemon.wikia.com/wiki/Nobi_Nobita):

> Nobita's eyes are never drawn consistently. **Sometimes they look like the number 3**, sometimes they're black beaded, and sometimes, like in the case of the recent movies, they're normal eyes.

[image]

Comment: I'll try to find a suitable image.

Comment: Then and now compared. http://girlschannel.net/topics/25131/